# Customizing Installshield's native ‘AskYesNo’ box

Tags: windows-installer, installation, installshield

Please tell me how to change the “Yes” and “No” buttons, in the default Installshield's native ‘AskYesNo’ question box, to “import” and “skip”.
Also please tell me how to change the title (which is natively displayed as 'Question') of the AskYesNo question box to a custom text.
Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps check this resource: http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/isp_ui.htm

Answer (score 0):

The default title is Question. To change the contents of the title bar, call SetDialogTitle before calling AskYesNo.

The AskYesNo message box is created by a direct call to the corresponding Windows API function, which displays a system modal dialog. Once a modal dialog is displayed, it retains focus until it is closed by the end user.

Because this dialog is displayed by Windows, the text in the buttons cannot be changed by the installation. That text—"Yes" and "No" in the English version—is displayed by Windows in the language appropriate to the version of Windows on which the installation is being run; no manual localization of this text is required. If you need to display a more flexible dialog, call a Windows API function directly or use a custom dialog.

i hope this help :)

source:
http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield19helplib/Subsystems/installshield19langref/helplibrary/LangrefAskYesNo.htm